# Nested 'while' loop needs to return information based on two query results being equal

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display a set of offices ordered under a header that reflects the state in which the offices are located, like so:

```
State
 Office
 Office
 ...
State
 Office
 ...
```

I have beat my head against this one for a while. There is a single table 'offices' in the MySQL db which has each office's State listed under 'office_state'. Here's what I've come up with - but nothing is returned.

```
// Here I return a list of the distinct States:
$stateQuery = 'SELECT DISTINCT office_state AS state FROM offices';
$stateResult = mysql_query($stateQuery);

// Here I return each office's information:
$officeQuery = 'SELECT office_information, office_state FROM offices';
$officeResult = mysql_query($officeQuery);

// And here's where I'm stuck:
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($stateResult)) {

    // This returns the distinct States:
    echo $rows['state'];

    // Here is my effort at listing each office within the State:
    $rows1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($officeResult);
    if ($rows['state'] == $rows1['office_state']) {
      echo $rows1['office_information'];

    }      
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: nothing is returned where? are you checking for errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<?php
// Here I return a list of the distinct States:
$stateQuery = 'SELECT DISTINCT office_state AS state FROM offices';
$stateResult = mysql_query($stateQuery);

// Here I return each office's information:
$officeQuery = 'SELECT office_information, office_state FROM offices';
$officeResult = mysql_query($officeQuery);

// And here's where I'm stuck:
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($stateResult)) {

    // Here is my effort at listing each office within the State:
    while($rows1 = mysql_fetch_array($officeResult)){
        if ($rows['state'] == $rows1['office_state']) {
          echo $rows1['office_information'];
        }
    }      
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks kindly Jivani - took some further doing, but this set me on the right path. Couple other helpful hints here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730128/php-double-while-loop-second-loop-not-iterating-more-than-once